git commands faild because could'nt log in with git credentials
I can't login to my azure devops repo over git.
I removed the windows credentials for this case.
Then i type in the git command and the login in for the microsoft account is opened. After click next the following script error is shown:
git login
script error
Translated message:
An error has occurred in the script on this page.
The object does not support the property or method “addEventListener”
Do you want scripts on this page to continue to be executed?
Thanks for supporting me

I can reproduce the same:

You can close the Git Crendential Manager window, and it will ask you to enter the password：

Generate PAT and paste it in the git window above, it will proceed.
Or you can manually add the credential:

Search Credential manager from start menu, and click it.
Go to Windows Credential -> add a general credential:



Type git:https://dev.azure.com/yourorgname for address, type username, and paste Personal access token(PAT) as password:


Then you can try again the git command.

